# How-to determine Facebook app environment

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I have FB web app and it runs in should runs different environments:

- As web app
- As Facebook canvas app
- As Facebook tab app

How to determine these three different environments in my javascript code?

Comment: Check the width and height of the window.

Comment: You could in your Facebook app preferences, set url parameters in the link to your app. Facebook lets you link to different pages depending on the enviroment.

Comment: I use window.name for that — it different for FB app and FB tab app. But im not sure that this is the best way.